# A code which computes which is the nth day of the year

Tags: matlab

I want to write a matlab code to get which day is the first day of year and also get n and display which is the nth day of that year.
And also i don't know why it can not compare a(for example sat) and w(i)
(W=[sat,sun,....,fri]
Please help me I really can't make it work!

This is what I have done so far:

```
First=input('sat,sun,...,fri');
day=('a number between 1and 365');
day=mod(day,7);
w=[sat,sun,....,fri];
for i=1:7
    if first==w(i)
        disp(mod(i+day,7))
    end
end
```

Comment: First=input('sat,sun,...,fri');day=('a number between 1and 365');day=mod(day,7);w=[sat,sun,....,fri];for i=1:7 if first==w(i) disp(mod(i+day,7))  end end

Comment: Edit your question with your code. Please don't paste it into the comments

Answer (score 2):

Note the syntax in the code below. I noticed you had quite a lot of errors in your syntax. Also, I recommend you use `datenum`and `datestr` as in the code below. Run `help datenum` and `help datestr` to get more information about the functions.

```
% User selects a year as a double
year = input('Select a year: '); 

% the first day of that year as a value
date = datenum([num2str(year),'-01-01']); 

% Get the name of the first day and diplay it
first = datestr(date,'dddd'); 
disp(['The first day of ', num2str(year), ' was a ', first])

% get nth day from user
day = input('Choose a number between 1 and 365: '); 

% Add this value to the value of 1st jan on the selected year
newDate = date + day-1; 

% Turn this date into a string and display it
nth = datestr(newDate,'dddd-dd-mmmm'); 
disp(['Day ', num2str(day),' of ', num2str(year), ' was ', nth])
```

Comment: @user297564, please accept the answer if it correctly answers your question.